# Exception: ComponentSpace.SAML2.Exceptions.SAMLBindingException: The message is not an HTTP POST

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

I am getting below error when I try to configure my application with Azure AD. Any suggestions ?

7848/7: 10/31/2021 11:49:01 AM: Receiving an SSO response from a partner identity provider.
7848/7: 10/31/2021 11:49:01 AM: Service provider session (2aea9585-e1e1-42d2-a67e-ed47d6ef5f09) state:
7848/7: 10/31/2021 11:49:01 AM: Receiving response over HTTP POST.
7848/7: 10/31/2021 11:49:01 AM: HTTPS request:
GET /SAML/AssertionConsumerService.aspx HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
7848/7: 10/31/2021 11:49:01 AM: Exception: ComponentSpace.SAML2.Exceptions.SAMLBindingException: The message is not an HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the browser developer tools (F12) to capture the network traffic to see what's going on. After logging in at Azure AD, you should see an HTTP Post being sent to your assertion consumer service URL. Hopefully looking at the network traffic will shed light on the issue.

Comment: i have faced the same issue and browser showing 301 and throwing error Message is not HTTP Post.